# Sending csrf_token in JQuery .post method

Tags: jquery, django, csrf, django-csrf

How do alter my existing JQuery to pass a crsf_token to my django view;

```
$.post('/historicaldata/input_parameters/', 
            { selected_table: selected_table, selected_column: selected_column, selected_SDT: selected_SDT, selected_EDT: selected_EDT},
            function(data){
```

I currently recieve a 403 error when I try to post.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax), where this is explicitly covered?

Comment: I did try this before, by copying and calling the function, but the error persisted. i reverted to the template theat includes this  and tried again but same error. what else could be causing it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman would you like a copy of more to see if you ca figure out the problem

Comment: @DanielRoseman actually don't worry about it Michael Tabor fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <body>
      <!-- CONTENT -->

      <script>
        CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token }}";
      </script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$.post('/historicaldata/input_parameters/', 
            { csrfmiddlewaretoken: CSRF_TOKEN, elected_table: selected_table, selected_column: selected_column, selected_SDT: selected_SDT, selected_EDT: selected_EDT},
            function(data){
```

Comment: where was the typo? in the csrf_token script?

Comment: Instead of 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' I wrote 'scrfmiddlewaretoken', in ajax params.